# Decode DM code by webcam using python and pylibdmtx library

Tags: python

Here is the code where I decode an image but I don't know how to decode from the webcam.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from pylibdmtx import pylibdmtx

if __name__ == '__main__':

    image = cv2.imread('new.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    msg = pylibdmtx.decode(thresh)
    print(msg)
```

Result

```
[Decoded(data=b'09903010917072337', rect=Rect(left=1, top=7, width=128, height=122))]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work with your camera. Don't forget to add pylibdmtx library

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    msg = pylibdmtx.decode(thresh)
    print(msg)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        # press Q in order to stop the feed
        break
```

Comment: @Sneeu Hello thank you because of your quick response but the result i found . multiple empty array Please help me to solve this and the webcam is not going to open  C:\Users\刘\PycharmProjects\Qrcode\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/刘/PycharmProjects/project_detect_DM_code/DM_webcam_D.py                                                                             here is the result----->       [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []